# Postgres pg_restore command to restore complete schema

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

am using Postgres EnterpriseDB 9.5.0.5

I have taken a schema dump by using the below command

```
pg_dump -n 'schema1' db1 > schema1.dump
```

Now i want to restore it in different database (db2) what is the command i have to use.

i tried

```
pg_restore -d DB2 schema1.dump;
```

but it is showing error

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archiver
```

Comment: Your `pg_dump` command creates a SQL script - not a "custom archive". You need to use `pg_dump --format=c` if you want to use `pg_restore`

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. if you include no -f option for pg_dump, it creates a sql script so then restore using psql, not pg_restore
2. You could add -fc to create a custom binary/compressed format and then use pg_restore as you are trying to do.

However pg_restore mostly converts the archive to an SQL script, so it is not useful when you start with an sql script.

Answer (score 0):

`pg_dump -Fc mydb > db.dump`

`pg_restore -c -d mydb db.dump`